# Producer-Consumer queue. How to add a Consume delay timer

Tags: java, timer, delay, producer-consumer

I am writing an internet data crawler. The logic is simple, Producer finds URL links to crawl, put batches of this urls in cycle to Queue, then Consumer pick this links from queue one by one and loads the HTML document on each link and processes it.

```
PRODUCER -> urls batch -> QUEUE -> one URL -> CONSUMER
```

The problem is that I need to add a delay to consumer, because the consumer make download requests too fast. The internet servers thinks that I am trying to DDOS them and blocks my requests.

I need to add some kind of countdown. When consumer pick url from queue, it starts countdown equals to 200ms. After it completed process url, it needs to check timer, if 200ms has not passed, it must wait before pick new url.

Comment: Use blank line and 4 spaces to format your code.

Comment: @xenteros I don't have code in my post

Comment: And that's the point!

Comment: As you particularly are interested in a crawler solution: You should download the `robots.txt` file located in the base path of the domain and check for things like `Allow` and `Crawl-delay`. If you can't find an entry for your crawler (or the general entry) you should at least wait enough time before crawling from that domain again (like 4 seconds is often recommended). The delay however is not directly in the [standard](https://web.archive.org/web/19990117080302/http://info.webcrawler.com/mak/projects/robots/norobots.html).

Comment: For a technical delay have a look at [DelayQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put : *Java DelayQueue Example* to Google and .. magic! Here is it!

You have to your object (maybe downloaded URL or whatever) and implements **Delayed** interface. Then you have a **Producer** which will keep data into **BlockingQueue** and last one is **Consumer**. This is simple solution with concurrency.
Tutorial is here for example: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/delayqueue/java-util-concurrent-delayqueue-example/

If you will share a code with us, maybe we will help with YOUR own implementation ;)

---

**EDIT**

As you wrote in comment that it is not working for you. Share your already wroted code here.
This will work if you have it correctly implemented. We don't know how you storing URLs, how you getting them and from which collection? Your question is very general.

Comment: And ... it is not working. If I add 10 urls with delay 200ms in same time, thay all execute in same time after 200 ms.

Comment: @Redeemer are the 10 urls all for the same domain or for different ones? If they are for different ones, this is actually desirable behavior. If they however point to the same domain, you should have a map where you manage the domains and when you last crawled them. If URIs get forwarded by the delay queue you need to check if the last crawl is longer then n timeunits (what ever your delay is) ago and if so crawl the URI otherwise push them back onto the queue with a new delay (the minimum delay for the domain)